# How can I save JSON data from an API service to cache?

Tags: angularjs

I call the API service from the backend side. I want to save the JSON return data to the cache. What should I do? Is my format wrong?

The snippet code here:

```
    // var localData = [];

    var service = {
    search: function(requestId) {
    return $http.get('/api/mace/getRequest', {
            params: {
                id: requestId
            },
            cache:true
    });
},
return service
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that there's something wrong with your code. You did correctly set the `cache` variable to true in the http-call as described in the [documentation from AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching).

```
$http.get(url, {
  cache: true
}
```

You should get your JSON by calling your service function and waiting for the promise:

```
yourService.search(yourRequestId).then(function(response) {
  console.log('result', response.data);
});
```